# How to modify a property value of a nested struct

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I'm trying to modify the value of a nested struct's variable in Go. Basically, I want to modify the `RsvpString` property but `GetRsvp()` seems to return the value of `Rsvp` instead of a reference, so when I modify its property value, it doesn't get reflected in the `Event` instance.

The test is below.

```
type Event struct {
    Rsvps     []Rsvp `json:"rsvps"`
}

type Rsvp struct {
    UserId          string `json:"userId"`
    RsvpString      string `json:"rsvp"`
}

func (e *Event) GetRsvp(userId string) (rsvp *Rsvp, err error) {
    for _, element := range e.Rsvps {
        if element.UserId == userId {
            return &element, nil
        }
    }
    return &Rsvp{}, fmt.Errorf("could not find RSVP based on UserID")
}

func (e *Event) UpdateExistingRsvp(userId string, rsvpString string) {
    rsvp, err := e.GetRsvp(userId)
    if err == nil {
        rsvp.RsvpString = rsvpString
    }
}
```

Here's the test code:

```
func TestEvent_UpdateExistingRsvp(t *testing.T) {
    e := Event{[]Rsvp{
        {Name:      "Bill",
            UserId:    "bill",
            Rsvp:      "yes"}}}

    e.UpdateExistingRsvp("bill", "no")
    assert.Equal(t, "no", e.Rsvps[0].Rsvp, "RSVP should be switched to no") // fails
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetRsvp` is returning the address of the loop variable, not the address of the element in the array. To fix:

```
    for i, element := range e.Rsvps {
        if element.UserId == userId {
            return &e.Rsvps[i], nil
        }
    }
```

The loop variable keeps a copy of e.Rsvps[i], and it gets overwritten at every iteration. If you return the address of the loop variable, then you return the address of that copy.

Comment: Thank you, this makes complete sense. I was missing the awareness that the loop variable makes a copy.

Comment: BTW I find for cases like this that I prefer (stylistically) just using `for i := range e.Rsvps {` (and then bind a local pointer to `&e.Rsvps[i]` if the test gets complicated).

Answer (score 0):

When ranging over a slice, two values are returned for each iteration. The first is the index, and the second is a copy of the element at that index.

so technically you are trying to modify the copy of the Rsvp.
instead, return the index and from the GetRsvp() method and update.

```
func (e *Event) GetRsvp(userId string) (int, error) {
    for index , element := range e.Rsvps {
        if element.UserId == userId {
            return index, nil
        }
    }
    return -1 , fmt.Errorf("could not find RSVP based on UserID")
}

func (e *Event) UpdateExistingRsvp(userId string, rsvpString string) {
    index, err := e.GetRsvp(userId)

    if err != nil || index == -1  {
        fmt.Println("no such user")
    }
    e.Rsvps[index].RsvpString = rsvpString
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works as well but I wanted to stay away from using indices as return values. I have accepted Burak's answer because of this difference.